# MySQL subquery in select

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have the following scenario. i have three tables (users, sales, sales_details) Users to Sales is a 1 to 1 relationship and sales to sales_details is 1 to many.
I am running a query where I get all the sales for each user by joining all 3 tables without any issue. 
Query looks something like this

```
SELECT s.month as month,u.name as name, s.year as year, s.date as date,sum(sd.qty) as qty,sum(sd.qty*sd.value) as value,s.id as id,sum(sd.stock) as stock,s.currency as currency,s.user as user 
FROM sales as s     
left join sales_details as sd on s.id = sd.Sales 
inner join users as u on s.user = u.Id 
group by s.Id
```

What I want to do now is add an extra field in my query which will be a subquery.

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS total_yearly 
FROM (
    SELECT  sum(qty) as total 
    FROM sales 
    left join sales_details on sales.Id = sales_details.Sales 
    WHERE ((month <= MONTH(NOW()) and year = YEAR(NOW())) 
        or (month >= MONTH(Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month)) and year = YEAR(Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month)))) 
        and User = **ID OF USER** ) as sub
```

This query on its own gives me the sales for the user for the past 12 months while the original query does it per month. I know that the result will be the same for each user but i need it for other calculations.
My problem is how I will join the 2 queries so that the subquery will read the user id from the original one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to do `SUM(total)`? There's only one `total`, so the sum is the same as the value.

Comment: Change the second query to be `GROUP BY User`, then join the two queries `ON s.id = sub.User`.

Comment: You are right the sum(total) is useless. Can you give a full example of the join?

Comment: The first query returns an indeterminate month see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want. etc..

Comment: So there is no way that I can join the two in a single query? What about @Barmar suggestion?

Comment: You can join them, but you're joining a query that doesn't make sense on its own. Shouldn't the first query be `GROUP BY s.id, s.month` so you get per-month totals? If not, why are you including `s.month` in the `SELECT` list?

Comment: Actually, I suspect the first query should be grouped by `s.month`, not `s.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the second query by user, and then join it with the original query.

```
SELECT s.month as month,u.name as name, s.year as year, s.date as date,
       sum(sd.qty) as qty,sum(sd.qty*sd.value) as value,s.id as id,
       sum(sd.stock) as stock,s.currency as currency,s.user as user,
       us.total
FROM sales as s     
left join sales_details as sd on s.id = sd.Sales 
inner join users as u on s.user = u.Id 
inner join (
    SELECT User, sum(qty) as total 
    FROM sales 
    left join sales_details on sales.Id = sales_details.Sales 
    WHERE ((month <= MONTH(NOW()) and year = YEAR(NOW())) 
        or (month >= MONTH(Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month)) and year = YEAR(Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month)))))
    GROUP BY User) AS us ON s.user = us.user
group by s.Id
```

Comment: This works like a charm @Barmar! Thank you so much.
I need to ask you something more, I want to add a field which will count how many months have actual sales (sum(qty)>0) during the past year of the subquery. 
The other thing is if I can run the subquery based on the month and year of the actual sales instead of NOW().

Comment: Use `SUM(qty > 0)` for to get the sum of months with sales. Although if you don't have any records in months without sales, just use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second question. You can group the subquery by month and year, and then use that in the joining condition.

Comment: Regarding the first question, if I put the sum(qty>0) I get the number of entries in the sales_details table. What I need is a number between 0 and 12 in order to know out of the year how many months had sales.

Comment: `SUM(qty>0)` should be the number of entries in the `sales_details` table where `qty > 0`. If there are 12 rows in the table, this will be a number between 0 and 12.

Comment: BTW, your date comparison gets 13 months of sales, because it includes the current month in this year and the previous year.

Comment: `qty` is a field in `sales_details` so there are a lot more than 12 entries. Its the `sales` table where I should do the count. Thanks for the point regarding the months.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT sales_details.month)` should do it.

Comment: It sure does @Barmar ! Now regarding the other part of my question, each `sales` entry has a `month` and `year` field. What I need is instead of this `WHERE ((month <= MONTH(NOW()) and year = YEAR(NOW())) 
        or (month >= MONTH(Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month)) and year = YEAR(Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month)))))` which always produces the same result to take into account the `month` and `year` of the actual `sales` entry and go one year back from that.

Comment: Sounds like you need to post a new question. I don't really understand what you mean by the actual sales entry. If you're grouping sales by month, then there's no single sales entry whose date to use. Post a new question with sample data and the desired result.